# Q : Best way to loop over a csv/dat file to access individual rows in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

Generally, we use `while` `for` `read` combination to loop over `csv`/`dat` files and then render each row accordingly in mailing report using HTML.

This is for point automation in our Linux machines where data set is not huge & normally ranges in between 100 - 150 rows.

Is there another way to do the same, which is faster and "makes more sense" cause heard that generally one shouldn't use `while` to perform the said ask.

PS : If there's another post with exact details, please attach it.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Where did you hear that? It's the normal way to loop over file lines.

Comment: [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Read the answer for the full context. If you're going to call a command on each line, it's usually better to just pass the file to the command. E.g. it's better to use `cut -f1 < file` instead of `while read line; do echo "$line" | cut -f1; done`

Comment: Yes i read that & i do use `cut`, `awk` and other combinations to shred the rows as per requirement. And on each loop that might change based on `if-else` condition too. Hence, i wondered if that is also true in my case or not. As per you, it isn't? & i can continue using `while` with `read` right ?

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.